# Join returning null columns?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a MYSQL query selecting from two tables.  The second table may not necessarily have a matching join id to the first table.  Let's use these two as examples:

```
++++++++++++++++++
table: t1
column: id
column: test_id
column: info

table t2
column: t2id
column: test_id
column: extra_info
++++++++++++++++++
```

I inserted these following rows into the table (this is just all pseudo at the moment):

```
insert into t1 values (1, 4, "asd")
insert into t1 values (2, 25, "dfg")
insert into t2 values (1, 25, "123")
```

Now my goal is to join the two tables together, but I am having issues with the join.  if the second table (t2) doesn't seem to have a matching row it makes the join column in the original table NULL?  Why is it doing this?  Here is an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` ON (`t1.test_id` = `t2.test_id`) WHERE `t1.id` = 1;
```

Now I have absolutely no issues if they match up, but for some reason if there is no row that exists, then test_id from t1 is being set as NULL...My goal is to join these two tables if there is something to join.  **EDIT: If there is nothing to join then i want to just return the data from t1 by either having all the t2 columns set to NULL or just returning the t1 data.**  Do I need to do a subquery?  and if so what would it be?  Thanks :)

Comment: LEFT [OUTER] JOIN means "keep every record on the left" -- this includes records that are *not* joined to a record on the right.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Can you give an example of the expected result?

Comment: Errr, I realize now I may have been a little unclear in what I want.  What I am trying to do is get the first table's information and add on the second table's information if it exists.  If it does not exist then just give me the first table with the second table all set to NULL or just the first table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` 
INNER JOIN `t2` ON (`t1.test_id` = `t2.test_id`) 
WHERE `t1.id` = 1;
```

Documentation on JOIN types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Errr, I think i was unclear in what I wanted to try and do.  Check my edit on the original post.

Comment: Your edits suggest that your original query should work as stated in your question? If not, provide some kind of expected output. Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db3b/3

Comment: I messed around with sql fiddle and I put in pretty much my exact query with a few left joins and it worked fine...maybe my framework is doing something sketchy when it comes to these joins because it seems to be dropping multiple values from the result and setting them to null if the row isn't matched....

Comment: The only solution I have found so far is to alias the columns that are being set to NULL if the join doesn't work so i can preserve the values...

Comment: As other answers have alluded to already, you really should avoid using `SELECT *`.

Comment: I am selecting like 20-25 values between all of the tables, and when i tried to alias a few it didn't seem to work =/  do u suggest I write out every individual piece of data I want to grab and alias them all?

Comment: You should make a reference to each column, yes, since if the table structure should change, your data output is not affected.

Comment: I think i may have just realized a possible reason why the information is being lost, but I am not sure on the solution.  On one of my join for my second left join i am joining on a value, not between two columns in the database...how would I go about making sure that it only joins the 2nd left join if the test_id's match (because they do share the same value between columns) and this external id (which i provide and compare to the 3rd table's id)?  I also have a simple where condition at the end of this mess which relates to the original table selected...

Answer (score 1):

That's the definition of `LEFT JOIN`. It returns rows even if only the left half of the join matches, filling the right side with `NULL` if needed.

If you want to get only the rows where there's a corresponding right side, use just `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

When joining, it is advisable not to use "SELECT *", particularly when you have similarly named columns in multiple tables, as this introduces ambiguity, and you may not get the result intended.  I would suggest instead:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.t2id, t2.extra_info 
FROM `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `t2` 
    ON (`t1.test_id` = `t2.test_id`)
WHERE `t1.id` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different types of joins. I think what you want is "inner join", where only rows that have a match are returned. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp